# Extract parts of chunked data in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a data that looks like this:

```
INFO  : Reading PDB list file 'model3.list'
INFO  : Successfully read 10 / 10 PDBs from list file 'model3.list'
INFO  : Successfully read 10 Chain structures
INFO  : Processed 40 of 45 MAXSUBs
INFO  : CPU time = 0.02 seconds
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : 3D-Jury (Threshold: >    10 pairs @ > 0.200)
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Rank     Model    Pairs       File
INFO  :     1 :        1      151       pdbs2/model.165.pdb
INFO  :     2 :        7      145       pdbs2/model.150.pdb
INFO  :     3 :        6      144       pdbs2/model.144.pdb
INFO  :     4 :        9      142       pdbs2/model.125.pdb
INFO  :     5 :        4      137       pdbs2/model.179.pdb
INFO  :     6 :        8      137       pdbs2/model.191.pdb
INFO  :     7 :       10      137       pdbs2/model.147.pdb
INFO  :     8 :        3      135       pdbs2/model.119.pdb
INFO  :     9 :        5      131       pdbs2/model.118.pdb
INFO  :    10 :        2      129       pdbs2/model.128.pdb
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Pairwise single linkage clustering
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Hierarchical Tree
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Node     Item 1   Item 2      Distance
INFO  :     0 :        6        1        0.476  pdbs2/model.144.pdb  pdbs2/model.165.pdb
INFO  :    -1 :        7        4        0.484  pdbs2/model.150.pdb  pdbs2/model.179.pdb
INFO  :    -2 :        9        2        0.576  pdbs2/model.125.pdb  pdbs2/model.128.pdb
INFO  :    -3 :       -2        0        0.598
INFO  :    -4 :       10       -3        0.615  pdbs2/model.147.pdb
INFO  :    -5 :       -1       -4        0.618
INFO  :    -6 :        8       -5        0.620  pdbs2/model.191.pdb
INFO  :    -7 :        3       -6        0.626  pdbs2/model.119.pdb
INFO  :    -8 :        5       -7        0.629  pdbs2/model.118.pdb
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : 1 Clusters @ Threshold  0.800 (0.8)
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Item     Cluster
INFO  :     1 :        1                        pdbs2/model.165.pdb
INFO  :     2 :        1                        pdbs2/model.128.pdb
INFO  :     3 :        1                        pdbs2/model.119.pdb
INFO  :     4 :        1                        pdbs2/model.179.pdb
INFO  :     5 :        1                        pdbs2/model.118.pdb
INFO  :     6 :        1                        pdbs2/model.144.pdb
INFO  :     7 :        1                        pdbs2/model.150.pdb
INFO  :     8 :        2                        pdbs2/model.191.pdb
INFO  :     9 :        2                        pdbs2/model.125.pdb
INFO  :    10 :        2                        pdbs2/model.147.pdb
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Centroids
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Cluster  Centroid  Size        Spread
INFO  :     1 :        1       10        0.566  pdbs2/model.165.pdb
INFO  :     2 :        10       3        0.777  pdbs2/model.147.pdb
INFO  : ======================================
```

And it constitutes a chunk of many more data. 
The chunks are denoted with starting line

```
INFO  : Reading PDB list file 'model3.list'
```

What I want to do is to extract parts of chunk here:

```
INFO  : ======================================
INFO  : Cluster  Centroid  Size        Spread
INFO  :     1 :        1       10        0.566  pdbs2/model.165.pdb
INFO  :     2 :        10       3        0.777  pdbs2/model.147.pdb
INFO  : ======================================
```

At the end of the day a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{1:"10 pdbs2/model.165.pdb", 
 2:"3 pdbs2/model.147.pdb"}
```

Namely with cluster number as key and values as cluster size + file_model name.

What's the way to achieve that in Python?

I'm stuck with this code:

```
import csv
import json
import os
import argparse
import re

def main():
    """docstring for main"""
    file = "max_cluster_output.txt"

    with open(file, 'r') as tsvfile:
        tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=' ')

        for line in tabreader:
            linelen = len(line)
            if "Centroids" in line:
                print line
                #if linelen >= 32 and linelen <= 34:
                #    print linelen, line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to start writing the code yourself? If not, then your question is off-topic: SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using regexes.

I would have an outer loop that

- reads lines until it finds "INFO  : Reading PDB list file"
- reads lines until it finds "INFO  : Cluster  Centroid  Size        Spread"
- inner loop that:

  - creates dictionary entries from each subsequent line, until the line no longer matches

    `INFO: <number> : <number> <number> <number> <string>`

It would look something like this (**not tested**):

```
import re

FILENAME = "foo.txt"

info = {}

try:
    with open(FILENAME) as f:
        while True:
            for line in f:
                if re.match("^INFO\s+:\s+Reading PDB list file", line):
                    break

            for line in f:
                if re.match("^INFO\s+:\s+Cluster\s+Centroid\s+Size\s+Spread", line):
                    break

            # We're up to the data

            for line in f:
                # look for INFO : Cluster-number Centroid-number Size-number spread-blah File-string
                match = re.match(^INFO\s+:\s+(?P<Cluster>\d+)\s+\d+\s+(?P<Size>\d+).*\s(?P<FileName>\S+)$, line)
                if match:
                    info[match.group("Cluster")] = "%s %s" % (match.group('Size'), match.group("FileName"))
                else:
                    break

except StopIteration:
    print "done"
```

This code is here just to show the types of things to use (looping, file iterator, breaking, regexes) ... its by no means necessarily the most elegant way (and it is not tested).

Comment: Note: it is implied by your "problem statement" that no two chunks will have the same cluster numbers. Because if they do, you have to decide what to do about detecting a cluster you already added and deciding what to do about it.